# Trying to randomise a game of rock, paper, scissors in R

Tags: r

I have created an RPS function that randomises the computer's move for one turn. For example, if you type in rps("rock"), the function will randomly spit out either rock, paper, scissors along with the result (win,loss,tie).

```
rps = function(move){
  options = c("rock", "paper", "scissors")
  comp.move = sample(options, size = 1)
  if(move == "rock" & comp.move == "rock"){
    names(comp.move) = "tie"
}else
if(move == "rock" & comp.move == "scissors"){
    names(comp.move) = "loss"
}else
if(move == "rock" & comp.move == "paper"){
    names(comp.move) = "win"
}else
if(move == "paper" & comp.move == "paper"){
    names(comp.move) = "tie"
}else
if(move == "paper" & comp.move == "scissors"){
    names(comp.move) = "win"
}else
if(move == "paper" & comp.move == "rock"){
    names(comp.move) = "loss"
}else
if(move == "scissors" & comp.move == "scissors"){
    names(comp.move) = "tie"
}else
if(move == "scissors" & comp.move == "rock"){
    names(comp.move) = "win"
}else
if(move == "scissors" & comp.move == "paper"){
    names(comp.move) = "loss"
}
  return(comp.move)
}
```

Now, I want to play a version of the game where this happens 50 times. I have already created a vector of length 50 that has the prerecorded human moves.

```
human.move = c("rock", "paper", "scissors", "paper", "paper", "rock", "scissors", "rock", "rock", "paper", "paper", "scissors", "rock", "rock", "paper", "paper", "paper", "scissors", "paper", "rock", "paper", "rock", "rock", "scissors", "scissors", "paper", "rock", "paper", "scissors", "rock", "paper", "paper", "scissors", "rock", "paper", "rock", "paper", "paper", "scissors", "scissors", "paper", "rock", "rock", "scissors", "scissors", "rock", "paper", "scissors", "scissors", "rock")
```

How do I get the computer to run the rps function on each element in this vector, and give me the results? Currently my function just takes the first element of my human moves vector (which is rock) and only compares its random moves to that.

```
rps.random=function(move,n=50){
comp.moves = vector("character")

for(i in human.move){
comp.move=rps(move[i])
comp.moves = append(comp.moves,comp.move, after = length(comp.moves))
}
return(comp.moves)
}
```

Comment: Many of the responses below are great, and involve rewriting much of the original OP's code. The question, however, was "How do I get the computer to run the rps function on each element in this vector, and give me the results?"

Comment: @GaryWeissman - That is true, but sometimes it can be better to offer improvements to the OP's current methods.

Comment: @RichardScriven that is true, too.

Comment: All this advanced coding and nobody's pointed out the fundamental flaw?  The game needs to include the options "lizard," and "Spock" !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a couple of suggestions.  First, an update to your function.  You can cut down on all those `if()` statements by using a few "or" statements with the `|` operator for either win or loss, and the `identical()` function for a tie.  Also, it is my understanding that randomized games such as this one should be played a single round at a time, and replicated for more than one round.  Therefore, this function checks for a single-length vector given in `move`.

```
rps <- function (move) {
    opts <- c("rock", "paper", "scissors")
    stopifnot(length(move) == 1L, move %in% opts)
    cpu <- sample(opts, 1)
    names(cpu) <- if (identical(move, cpu)) {
        "tie"
    }
    else if (move == "rock" & cpu == "scissors" | move == "paper" & 
        cpu == "rock" | move == "scissors" & cpu == "paper") {
        "win"
    }
    else {
        "loss"
    }
    cpu
}
```

Here are a couple of example runs -

```
rps("paper")
#    win 
# "rock" 
rps("rock")
#    loss 
# "paper"
```

Now you don't need to manually create a vector of 50 items.  We can just replicate the process 50 times by using a sample in the `move` argument.

```
replicate(50, rps(sample(c("rock", "paper", "scissors"), 1)))
#        win        win       loss        win       loss        tie        tie 
# "scissors"    "paper"    "paper"    "paper"     "rock"    "paper" "scissors" 
#        win       loss       loss        tie       loss        win        win 
#     "rock"    "paper"    "paper"    "paper"    "paper" "scissors" "scissors" 
#        tie       loss        tie        win        win        tie       loss 
# "scissors"     "rock" "scissors"    "paper"    "paper" "scissors"     "rock" 
#        tie        tie       loss        tie        win        win        win 
#     "rock" "scissors" "scissors" "scissors"     "rock" "scissors" "scissors" 
#        win        win       loss        win        tie        tie        win 
# "scissors" "scissors"    "paper"    "paper"    "paper"    "paper"    "paper" 
#        win        tie        win        tie        tie        win        win 
#    "paper"     "rock"     "rock"    "paper" "scissors"    "paper" "scissors" 
#       loss        tie        tie       loss        tie        win        win 
#     "rock"     "rock"    "paper" "scissors" "scissors"     "rock"     "rock" 
#        win 
#    "paper"
```

Of course, if you did have an input vector we can run it through `sapply()` to see the same results as above (with or without the input vector in the names).

```
sapply(c("rock", "paper", "scissors"), rps)
#   rock.loss    paper.win scissors.tie 
#     "paper"       "rock"   "scissors" 
sapply(c("rock", "paper", "scissors"), rps, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#       tie       loss        win 
#    "rock" "scissors"    "paper"
```

**Update:** It just dawned on me that you will have no idea what the input was in the above cases that we got from `replicate()`, so here is a fix.  If we change the last line if the function to a matrix (or a list), we can also include what the input was.  We can use something like this for the last line =

```
matrix(c(move, cpu), 1, dimnames = list(wlt, c("move", "cpu")))
```

Then we would get the following for results -

```
rps("paper")
#      move    cpu       
# loss "paper" "scissors"
rps("paper")
#     move    cpu    
# tie "paper" "paper"
```

Now we know what we put in as input without doing any extra work.  And we can also bring replications together into a matrix with our old friend `do.call(rbind, ...)`.

Answer (score 6):

As Gary suggested, for any function that works on 'one thing', you can use `lapply` or `sapply` to make it work for many things.

But I'd say that's not really necessary here because what's inside `rps` already handles the situation when `move` is longer than 1. You'd just need to change `sample(options, size = 1)` to `sample(options, size = length(move), replace = TRUE)`.

Google 'sampling with replacement' if you're not sure about the the `replace = TRUE` part.

I think there's also a simpler way to figure out whether it was a win, loss or tie.

```
rps = function(move){

  # possible selections
  options = c("rock", "paper", "scissors")

  # the sample function is already vectorised, so it will work when
  # move is longer than one
  comp.move = sample(options, size = length(move), replace = TRUE)

  #create a result vector that defaults to 'loss'
  results <- rep('loss', length(move))

  # update the rest of the results (these are vectorised too)
  results[move == comp.move]                             <- 'tie'
  results[move == 'rock'      & comp.move == 'scissors'] <- 'win'
  results[move == 'paper'     & comp.move == 'rock']     <- 'win'
  results[move == 'scissors'  & comp.move == 'paper']    <- 'win'

  # set the names
  names(comp.move) <- results

  # return the vector
  comp.move
}
```

Then you can use it like so

```
> rps(human.move)
      loss        win        win       loss       loss        win       loss        tie       loss       loss       loss       loss        win        win 
   "paper"     "rock"    "paper" "scissors" "scissors" "scissors"     "rock"     "rock"    "paper" "scissors" "scissors"     "rock" "scissors" "scissors" 
      loss       loss       loss       loss        tie        tie       loss        tie        tie       loss        tie        win        tie        tie 
"scissors" "scissors" "scissors"     "rock"    "paper"     "rock" "scissors"     "rock"     "rock"     "rock" "scissors"     "rock"     "rock"    "paper" 
       tie        win       loss       loss        win       loss       loss        win       loss        tie        tie        tie        win       loss 
"scissors" "scissors" "scissors" "scissors"    "paper"    "paper" "scissors" "scissors" "scissors"    "paper" "scissors" "scissors"     "rock"    "paper" 
       tie        win        tie        tie       loss        tie        tie        tie 
    "rock"    "paper" "scissors"     "rock" "scissors" "scissors" "scissors"     "rock"
```

Answer (score 5):

kek

```
rps <- function(player) {
  p <- c('rock','paper','scissors')
  player <- if (missing(player))
    sample(p, 1) else match.arg(player, p, FALSE)
  computer <- sample(p, 1)
  message(sprintf('Computer picks %s', computer))
  message(sprintf('You chose %s', player))
  plays <- cbind(expand.grid(p = p, c = p),
                 result = I(c('tie','win','loss','loss','tie','win','win','loss','tie')))

  res <- plays[plays$p %in% player & plays$c %in% computer, 'result']
  if (res == 'tie')
    return(res)

  for (ii in 1:10) {
    par(mar = c(0,0,0,0), bg = sample(colors(), 1))
    plot(1:10, ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE, type = 'n')
    text(runif(1, 1, 10), runif(1, 1, 10), toupper(res), srt = sample(0:360, 1),
         font = 3, cex = 4, col = sample(colors(), 1))
    Sys.sleep(.1)
  }
  graphics.off()
  res
}

rps()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `apply` family of functions. In your case, try:

```
lapply(human.move, rps)
```